# Loading memory of Android device

Tags: android, memory, memory-management, bitmap

I want to load memory/RAM of the Android device using large number of images. How can I load huge bitmaps into a list in a cycle/loop?

I am new to Android and have never used bitmaps before. I tried drawable images but that didn't work.

Comment: use universal image loader library or volley or many more in android...

Comment: Am I dreaming or you already tried to ask this [yesterday](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36416885/loading-memory-of-android-device) ??

Comment: yes I tried to ask the same question yesterday.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/blob/master/README.md) or [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) or [Volley Library](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-volley/). They take care of lazy loading and caching for you.